# How to get accumulated price in a nested array using reduce in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reduce

In my mapStateToProps, I have an array of objects (products). In each object, there is an array of "addons", another array of objects. How can i accumulate the price of all "addons" for each product.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return ({
    ...state,
    totalItemsAddonPrice: ????,
    totalItemPrice: state.toggleCartReducer.cartItems.reduce((accumulatedQuantity, cartItem) => accumulatedQuantity + cartItem.quantity * cartItem.price, 0),
    itemCount: state.toggleCartReducer.cartItems.reduce((accumulatedQuantity, cartItem) => accumulatedQuantity + cartItem.quantity, 0),
    tax: state.toggleCartReducer.cartItems.reduce((accumulatedQuantity, cartItem) => accumulatedQuantity + cartItem.quantity * cartItem.price, 0) * .0725
})}
```

```
exampleData = [ 
    {
        name:"product1",
        price:10,
        addons: [
            {
                addonName: "first add on",
                addonPrice: 3
            },
            {
                addonName: "second add on",
                addonPrice: 1
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        name:"product2",
        price:15,
        addons: [
            {
                addonName: "product2 add on",
                addonPrice: 3
            },
            {
                addonName: "product2 second add on",
                addonPrice: 2
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

The goal is to get the total price...

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use nested reduce to find addon total like this.

```js
const exampleData = [ 
    {
        name:"product1",
        price:10,
        addons: [
            {
                addonName: "first add on",
                addonPrice: 3
            },
            {
                addonName: "second add on",
                addonPrice: 1
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        name:"product2",
        price:15,
        addons: [
            {
                addonName: "product2 add on",
                addonPrice: 3
            },
            {
                addonName: "product2 second add on",
                addonPrice: 2
            },
        ]
    }
]


const addOntotal = exampleData.reduce((totalPrice, item) =>
  totalPrice + item.addons.reduce((total, addon) => total + addon.addonPrice, 0), 0);
 
console.log(addOntotal)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make an array with all of the prices using [Array.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and then add them using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
exampleData
  .flatMap(item => [item.price, ...item.addons.map(a => a.addonPrice)])
  .reduce((total, price) => total + price, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
totalItemsAddonPrice = exampleData.reduce((accum, curr) => {
 return accum + curr.addons.reduce((acc, cur) => {
   return acc + cur.addonPrice
  }, 0)
}, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways of calculating the total addon price.

If you are comfortable with the `for` loop, [`For of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) could be used here.

```js
let price = 0;
for(const product of exampleData) {
  for(const addon of product.addons) {
    price+=addon.addonPrice
  }
}
```

The above code would iterate through exampleData.  Each element of exampleData would be held by the variable `product`.  `product` is an object with `addons` array.  Adding `addonPrice` from the object to the price gives the desired result.

However, if you are comfortable using the [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), the code is shorter, but it might take some time to wrap your head around it.

```js
const price = exampleData.reduce(
  (prodAcc, prod) => {
    return prodAcc + prod.addons.reduce(
      (addonAcc, curAddon) => {
        return addonAcc + curAddon.addonPrice
      }, 0
    )
  }, 0
)
```